# fread() fails to read file data in Dev-Cpp

Tags: c++, fopen, fread, dev-c++, errno

I am running into a strange situation. I use Dev C++ to write the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;     // edited -- wrong type at first (File)
    unsigned char a, b;
    int c, count, res;      // added "res"
    short int d;

    fp = fopen("record.dat", "r");
    fseek(fp, SEEK_SET, 0);
    count = 0;    // edited -- wrong variable name at first

    res = fread(&a, 1, 1, fp);
    printf("a res = %d, errno %d\n", res, errno);
    while(count < 10) {
        count++;
        res = fread(&b, 1, 1, fp);    // added "res =" as mentioned in comment
        printf("b res = %d, errno %d\n", res, errno);
        res = fread(&c, 4, 1, fp);    // added "res =" as mentioned in 
        printf("c res = %d, errno %d\n", res, errno);
        res = fread(&d, 2, 1, fp);    // added "res =" as mentioned in 
        printf("d res = %d, errno %d\n", res, errno);
        res = fread(&a, 1, 1, fp);    // ** where problem starts
        printf("a res = %d, errno %d\n", res, errno);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

The "record.dat" file is over 1MB in size, so I suppose the above program can get the data of the first 10 records without any issue (e.g. no need to handle `EOF` issue). However, when I compile the program in Dev C++ and run it, after reading 4 records, the `fread()` (marked by ** above) returns 0, and then subsequent `fread()` inside the while loop also return 0, meaning no data can be read. The stranger thing is all `errno` are 0, and when I use a g++ compiler in Linux to compile the same program, the program can read all (not just 10) of the records in the same file without any problem.

Is there anything I have missed? Thanks!

Comment: If this is your exact code, then you're missing `res = ` before most of your `fread()`s, making the `printf()`s following them possibly misleading.

Comment: THis is C code: why the c++ tag ?

Comment: have you tried opening in binary mode ("rb")  just in case c or d would contain the equivalent of an EOF marker ?

Comment: @zenzelezz Thank you for spotting my programming bug. Unfortunately, the result is still the same after making the changes (3 occurrences).

Comment: @GreenPenguin  I don't see `res` declared in your code.

Comment: What is the successfully read data with g++ for the first few records?

Comment: @GreenPenguin  The code you posted wont even compile.

Comment: @Christophe Thanks for changing the tag. "rb" is the fix, I changed the parameter in fopen() from "r" to "rb", deleted the original executable and then re-compiled, it solved the problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: @ameyCU I have updated the code, sorry the original one was much simplified to eliminate some unrelated code segments, unfortunately it caused other errors.

Comment: @Christophe: Because it is being compiled with a C++ compiler. Therefore, it is actually C++ code and is subject to the rules of the C++ standard, ancestry and possible inheritance notwithstanding. Please do not mangle the tags like that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How do you know it's being compiled with a C++ compiler?

Comment: @melpomene: If the OP went to the trouble of modifying Dev-C++'s options to invoke a C compiler, he didn't mention it. Furthermore, his control is _"a g++ compiler in Linux"_ and he tagged the question [tag:c++]. Seems like a pretty safe bet to me.

Comment: @GreenPenguin: Christophe is right about one thing, though: you are writing this program in a completely C-compatible style, as if you were following the rules and idioms of the C language. That is not recommended in C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well, I'd have expected `#include <cstdio>` then.

Comment: @Christophe: `#include <cstdio>` is not required for invoking a C++ compiler. You can invoke a C++ compiler (and, thus, have a C++ program) without writing `#include <cstdio>`. I almost agree that the OP _should_ have written `#include <cstdio>` but, in fact, the OP should have avoided the C standard library entirely, most likely. In light of that, "expectations" rather fly out of the window, wouldn't you say? :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's not required but it would have shown the intent of writing C++ code.

Comment: @Christophe: Yes, it would have been nice. Clearly the OP is either not aware of the differences between C and C++, or doesn't really care about them. But, since the question was tagged [tag:c++], here we are to helpfully inform him now! If it were tagged [tag:c], we would not be able to. Meanwhile: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281387/560648

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're reading a binary file, you should open it with `"rb"`, not `"r"`. Otherwise you get (platform specific) "text mode" handling. On Linux this doesn't change anything, but on Windows this will translate CR/LF (`0D 0A`) to `'\n'` and may also interpret `^Z` as the end of the file.

You can confirm this by looking at a hex dump of the file: If your program mysteriously stops reading at `1A`, this is the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, I believe your answer pinpoints the problem I was facing. There was a "1A" when reading the file to the integer `c` in run #4 of the `while` loop.